# I have issue with selecting elements of array with json_decode

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have an issue with json_decode.  I have a variable `$response` that contains a json string like that:

```
{
  "access_token":"340",
  "user":{
    "username":"ferfer",
    "bio":"","website":""
  }
}
```

I decided to use `json_decode($response,true)` so I get an associative array like this:

```
array(2) { 
  ["access_token"]=> string(50) "340" 
  ["user"]=> array(6) { 
    ["username"]=> string(13) "ferdferd" 
    ["bio"]=> string(0) "" 
    ["website"]=> string(0) ""
  }
}
```

I need to get information from that but I don't know how.

I have tried to do `$access=$response[access_token]`, but if I echo that I do not get anything.

Comment: If `json_decode` gives you an associative array, why have you discarded an attempt and decided to read some properties off the string? Also, what's the language? It isn't Java or Javascript. Is it PHP? Also, chances are you need quotes if you want to access properties through the square bracket syntax.

Comment: @mrCode this does look like PHP, but are you sure?

Comment: Yes I am sure. No other language uses `json_decode()` in that way, uses the dollar for variables and shows a dumped array like that. The Java tag is the same thing that happens every day with Java != JavaScript.

Comment: @user3581365 did you take a look at my answer?

Comment: @MrCode yeah i tried to do like you told me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `json_decode()` function doesn't modify the variable in place, it returns the decoded object so you have to capture the return value:

[Codepad Demo](http://codepad.org/uqF0DVMX)

```
$result = json_decode($response,true);
$access = $result['access_token'];
```

Comment: What language is this? If you know the asker's language _for sure_ (do you?), please retag appropriately.

Comment: Agreed, re-tagged as PHP.

Comment: I still don't consider this question worth answering. It isn't going to be useful to future visitors, if only because there are plenty of resources saying this already. I have voted to close as unclear, but now it's "typo / trivial mistake" that applies.

Comment: I tried to do how you told me but i don't get any value i just get something like this string(1) "{"

Comment: @user3581365 it seems you are doing something that isn't shown in the question. See my updated answer that contains a working demo. Compare your code to that to see what you're doing differently.

Answer (score 0):

```
$items = $json_results['user'];
foreach ( $items as $item){

  echo $item['username'];
}
```

Did you mean like this? this should return Ferdferd, I think..